# how to pop all negative numbers from list with for loop without list comprehension in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm an getting error message saying
"Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 10, in 
if list1[j] < 0:
IndexError: list index out of range"

I am trying to get rid of all the negative number from the sample input "10 -7 4 39 -6 12 2" to make an output like this 10 4 39 12 2 trying to use pop to do this.

I couldn't figure out an exact fix for this, I've through google searched and searched on stackoverflow.

I don't want list comprehension as an answer

```
input1 = str(input())

list1 = input1.split()

for i in range(len(list1)):
    list1[i] = int(list1[i])


for j in range(len(list1)):
        if list1[j] < 0:
            list1.pop(j)

print(list1)
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use `pop`? Since you aren't saving the value, you should probably use `del list1[index]`. In any cse, modifying a list while iterating it is 1) annoying to do correctly 2) very inefficient. You should instead *create a new list* be it with a list comprehension or with a regular loop

Comment: I have not learned list comprehension yet I'm trying to figure out how to do it with for loop, I've done it many times in the past with pop and it worked out with pop but nowadays I can't seem to figure it out I just want to know it so I know how to do it in case I need to do it in the future, I'll be learning list comprehension eventually. I tried the "del list1[j]" it still says the same exact error message.

Comment: Whether to use a list comprehension isn't really the issue. The difficulty is using `pop()` on the same list you are looping over, which is rarely a good idea. It's almost always better to make a new list by selectively `append()`ing to a new list if you must use a loop.

Comment: @Jamesx1080 again, the *issue is not using a list comprehension or not*. A list comprehension is essentially shorthand for a loop that appends to a list. Just do that loop. But *you should do it by creating a new list*. I've written an answer showing you how you *could* do it that way, but there is pretty much **never** a good reason to do it that way. So don't.

Comment: i am sorry if i didn't get ur question correctly, but is it okay if i make a new list and add all the positive numbers there?

Comment: you answered fine, but I realize it's more important to do the list comprehension with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you trying to use `pop`? Since you aren't saving the value, you should probably use `del list1[index]`.

In any case, modifying a list while iterating it is 1) annoying to do correctly 2) very inefficient. You should instead *create a new list* be it with a list comprehension or with a regular loop.

The fundamental problem is that when you remove an item, *all the indices after that have shifted*.

Naively, you might think you can do something like:

```
for i, e in enumerate(data):
    if e < 0:
        del data[i]
```

This won't throw the index error, however, if you have two negative numbers next to each other, it will *skip* one:

```
>>> data = [1,2, -3, -4, 5]
>>> for i,e in enumerate(data):
...     if e < 0:
...         del data[i]
...
>>> data
[1, 2, -4, 5]
>>>
```

But here are a couple of ways that you *could* do it.

#### Keep in mind, these algorithms are inefficient

The first, simply keep track of the number of items you have removed and adjust the indices accordingly:

```
>>> removed = 0
>>> data = [1,2, -3, -4, 5]
>>> for i in range(len(data)):
...     if data[i - removed] < 0:
...         del data[i - removed]
...         removed += 1
...
>>> data
[1, 2, 5]
```

Perhaps the simplest way is to use a while-loop, actually:

```
>>> data = [1,2, -3, -4, 5]
>>> i = 0
>>> while i < len(data):
...     if data[i] < 0:
...         del data[i]
...     else:
...         i += 1
...
>>> data
[1, 2, 5]
```

The important point above is to only increment `i` when you don't delete something.

And finally, you can simply iterate starting from the end of the list:

```
>>> data = [1,2, -3, -4, 5]
>>> for i in reversed(range(len(data))):
...     if data[i] < 0:
...         del data[i]
...
>>> data
[1, 2, 5]
>>>
```

To reiterate:

#### The above algorithms are all very inefficient.

They require linear space and *quadratic time*. You can create a new list in linear space and linear time.

Consider:

```
>>> data = [1,2, -3, -4, 5]
>>> new_data = []
>>> for x in data:
...     if x >= 0:
...         new_data.append(x)
...
>>> new_data
[1, 2, 5]
```

Or the equivalent list comprehension:

```
>>> data = [x for x in data if x >= 0]
>>> data
[1, 2, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
input1 = str(input())

list1 = input1.split()

ind_to_remove = []
for i in range(len(list1)):
    list1[i] = int(list1[i])
    if list1[i] < 0:
        ind_to_remove.append(i)

ind_to_remove.sort(reverse=True)
for ind in ind_to_remove:
    list1.pop(ind)

print(list1)
```

Comment: This won't work. Consider `list1 = [1,2,-3,-4,5]` or even `[1, -2, 3, -4, 5]`. Indeed, `[1, -2, 3, 4, -5]` would actually throw an error.

Comment: Added ind_to_remove.sort(reverse=True)

Comment: well, you *could* just do `for ind in reversed(ind_to_remove):` but at least the above will work.

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension is probably best practice, however this is how you could do this without one. What you are doing is iterating through the length of the initial list, but pop is shrinking your list so that the original indices are no longer applicable to the list (hence the error).

One way to do this is to use `.remove` on the list. This will remove the first element that matches the value, which will work in this case. This is more like a hack, because we use the `list()` function to return a copy of the list so that will iterate over the copy and get each value from the list while we modify it. If we didn't create a copy, the loop would skip some values. This is probably cleaner than the other methods posted here if you don't want a list comprehension or to create a new list (however you are essentially creating a new list with this method memory-wise).

```
lst = ["1", "-3", "-5", "-3", "10", "10", "11", "-4"]

for val in list(lst):
    if int(val) < 0:
        lst.remove(val)
    else:
        lst[lst.index(val)] = int(val)
```